# Combining Multiple Lists of Dictionaries while Writing to JSON file

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, io

I'm trying to write a JSON file after gathering a bunch of lists of dictionaries and writing a list of lists of dict. As of now the output has been appending the lists of dict with spaces. 
I want to figure out how to add brackets over the entire out put while separating each index with a comma.

** I want the JSON file to update after every deal in deals_list **

The url_page function outputs:

```
deals_list=[{u'all_deals_links': u'http://www.groupon.com/deals/the-ballet-academy-newark'}{u'all_deals_links': u'http://www.groupon.com/deals/clean-extreme-1'}]

[{....}]
```

This is the output:

```
[{"time_retrieved": "2014-11-06 09:45:28.619697", "amount_sold": ["Over 20 bought", "Over 10   bought”]}][{“time_retrieved": "2014-11-06 09:45:29.907905", "amount_sold": "Over 230 bought”}]
```

What I want is:

```
[[{..,{},..}]]

[[{"time_retrieved": "2014-11-06 09:45:28.619697", "amount_sold": ["Over 20 bought", "Over 10   bought”]}],[{“time_retrieved": "2014-11-06 09:45:29.907905", "amount_sold": "Over 230 bought”}]]
```

Basically the code goes through a list a groupon page links and extracts data with url_page

```
    page_data_list=[]


    with open('Updated_sample_groupon_page_data_test.json', 'a') as jsonfile:
        for data in range(starting_deal_number, len(deals_list)-1):
            page_data_list.append(url_page(str(deals_list[data]['all_deals_links'])))

            for f in page_data_list:    
                json.dump(f, jsonfile, encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: Why are you even opening the `jsonfile` object twice?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I thought I had to write it first and then open it for appending.

Comment: No, opening for appending will create the file too if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I am completely in the dark as to what you are trying to achieve, by the way. Have you got any sample input data and something more concrete that you want to see in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
page_data_list = []

for data in range(starting_deal_number, len(deals_list)-1):
    page_data_list.append(url_page(str(deals_list[data]['all_deals_links'])))

with open('Updated_sample_groupon_page_data_test.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    json.dump(page_data_list, jsonfile, encoding='utf8')
```

or more simply:

```
page_data_list = []

for deal in deals_list:
    page_data_list.append(url_page(str(deal['all_deals_links'])))

with open('Updated_sample_groupon_page_data_test.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    json.dump(page_data_list, jsonfile, encoding='utf8')
```

EDIT: If you must update the JSON file every time you append to `page_data_list`, and can afford the IO hit, just rewrite the whole list to the JSON file on each iteration:

```
page_data_list = []

for deal in deals_list:
    page_data_list.append(url_page(str(deal['all_deals_links'])))

    with open('Updated_sample_groupon_page_data_test.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
        json.dump(page_data_list, jsonfile, encoding='utf8')
```

I wouldn't recommend this, though, since as a general rule of thumb disk IO is always the biggest bottleneck, while RAM and CPU time are plentiful. Writing once in large block IO is also generally preferred over lots of smaller IO, which you would be doing if you manually mangled the output JSON and wrote just one item from page_data_list at a time. That said, the IO elevator on your OS may make that unnoticeable, depending on how often you're writing.

Comment: i mean, that instead of gathering the data in a list before hand and then putting it into the jsonfile, I want the jsonfile to be written to after every deal gathered in the deals_list

Comment: Hmm, I have to ask, why? Everything gets put into a list, so I presume there's not a memory constraint. And the JSON file wouldn't be valid JSON until you finish out the outer list.